# php : parse xml file Multi line strings

Tags: php, xml

I need to form a table for each road with a shape_leng and a coordinates(multilinestring) columns for each road there can be any number of lines for a road i need to save them in one row

Xml file is of this format: a few roads are multiline strings, and a few others have only one line:

And I have tried to parse it

(Note that **shape_leng** is single for a road, but  coordinate lines can be single or many for a road.)

So I am unable to add them in a particular order like *shape_leng* and *coordinates*.

Comment: I need to form a table for each road with a shape_leng and a coordinates(multilinestring) columns for each road there can be any number of lines for a road i need to save them in one row

Comment: you add order when you query the database to select from it, not when you insert the data. did that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to insert all coordinates into a single database row, I think you have to construct the XPath and loop a bit differently.  Loop through the roads, then use XPath to get all coordinates belonging to that road.  Eg:

```
// get all the roads and loop through them
$roads = $xml->xpath("//e:featureMember/b:AA_ROAD");
$i=0;

while(isset($roads[$i]))
{
    // get the coordinates for the current road
    $coordinates = $roads[i]->xpath("/b:the_geom/e:MultiLineString/e:lineStringMember/e:LineString/e:coordinates");
    $shapel = $roads[i]->xpath("/b:SHAPE_Leng");

    // add a second loop to concatinate all the $coordinates
    $j=0;
    while (isset($coordinates[$j])) {
        // TODO concatinate coordinates
    }

   // insert the row
   $b=mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO `new`.`road1` (`coordstr`, `shapeleng`) values (GEOMFROMTEXT(concat('MULTILINESTRING ($a )')), '$shapel[$i]') ");


    $i++;
    echo "<br />";
    echo $i;    
}
```

Comment: Iam getting an error for                                          $shapel = $roads[$i]->xpath("/b:SHAPE_Leng"); Warning: SimpleXMLElement::xpath() [<a href='simplexmlelement.xpath'>simplexmlelement.xpath</a>]: Undefined namespace prefix in C:\wamp\www\kgp\newroadp.php on line 14       $shapel = $roads[$i]->xpath("/b:SHAPE_Leng");